# Converting file to CSV

Tags: scala, csv

I have a flat text file that comes in the following format.

```
98430John        Smith       Y
98431Mary        Jones       N
98432Michael     Johnson     Y
```

- First 5 chars are the ID.
- Next 12 chars are the first name.
- Next 12 chars are the last name.
- Last 1 char is a Y/N value.

I've been using Java to open the file and split it file using substring and FileInputStream.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   String csvString = str.substring(5)+","str.substring(6, 18);
}

br.close();
```

I want to do the same thing now, but in Scala. I know that I can achieve this by importing Java libraries, but I am just wondering, is there a more elegant, pure Scala way to achieve this?

Comment: It's problems like this (where the solution - Java or Scala - basically sucks) that makes me thing Fortran format descriptors (http://www.obliquity.com/computer/fortran/format.html) weren't entirely a bad idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scala.io.Source](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source$) to read a file.

Example code (without exception handling!):

```
import scala.io.Source

// field lengths
val fieldLengths = List(5, 12, 12, 1)

// from field lengths to start pos: List(0, 5, 17, 29, 30)
val startPos = fieldLengths.foldLeft(List(0)){(acc, l) =>
  l + acc.head :: acc
}.reverse


// fields: List[List[String]] = List(List(98430, John, Smith, Y), List(98431, Mary, Jones, N),
val fields = Source.fromFile("/tmp/test.txt").getLines map { line =>
  startPos.zip(fieldLengths).map{ case (start, length) =>
      line.substring(start, start + length).trim
  }
}

// csv: String = 
//   98430,John,Smith,Y
//   98431,Mary,Jones,N
//  98432,Michael,Johnson,Y
val csv = fields.map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with i/o is probably never elegant, because you'd always have to consider the occurrence of an i/o-exception. As soon as you have to deal with exceptions, you no longer have nice functions (in a mathematical sense, i.e., no state and a deterministic result). There is one case that exceptional behavior can be dealt with elegantly: If exceptions are part of your result (e.g., if you are writing a test engine), you can specify the result to be of type `Try[Something]`. **So java.io or java.nio are okay choices**.

With testability in mind, **separate the i/o access from the transformations**. Read the input file first, as a whole (if it fits in memory at least), then transform it into a csv-string.

Your input format can be easily expressed as a regular expression, against which you can match the input lines. Assuming the ID is always an integer, the regexp could look as following: `(\d{5})(.{12})(.{12})([Y,N])`.

Given an iterator over the input lines, you can use a fold and a regexp-matcher to transform the input into a csv-string:

```
object ToCSV {

  val InputFormat = "(\\d{5})(.{12})(.{12})([Y,N])".r

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Assume the input to be read from file using a BufferedReader
    val input =
      """98430John        Smith       Y
        |98431Mary        Jones       N
        |98432Michael     Johnson     Y""".stripMargin
    val inputLines = input.lines 

    val csvString =
      (inputLines foldLeft "") {
        case (accumulator, InputFormat(id, firstName, lastName, yesOrNo)) =>
          s"$accumulator$id,${firstName.trim},${lastName.trim},$yesOrNo\n"
      }

    print(csvString)
  }
}
```

The beauty of matching against a regular expression is that your strings look like a tuple. In the code, `"#####firstName   lastName    X"` is indistinguishable from having an instance of a `case class InputFormat(id, firstName, lastName, yesOrNo)`.

**Edit**: Actually, you can get rid of the calls to `.trim` if you change the regular expression to `(\d{5})(\S{1,12})\s*(\S{1,12})\s*([Y,N])`, but then the first name and last name must not contain whitespaces.